# Xamarin.ios SIGSEGV error

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, segmentation-fault

I have ran into a big problem when debugging the IOS version of my PCL solution.

Other related questions I have read and tried did not help me or help me make any sense, feel free to ask more about my project because I do not know what is necessary for you to know

> The error is : An error occurred while executing MTouch.

In the output it shows this :

```
InspectorDebugSession(0): StateChange: Start -> EntryPointBreakpointRegistered
InspectorDebugSession(0): Constructed
Launching 'LiquitMobileApp.iOS' on 'iPhone 6s iOS 10.3'...
InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: TargetReady
Loaded assembly: /Users/kevin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5DDB04B6-3BFA-4390-B22D-0492BAD99E3A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33A8D304-D62D-43A3-9839-C0A43FF720C6/LiquitMobileApp.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[], string, string)' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:61 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[], System.Type, System.Type)' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:68 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[])' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:73 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[], System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr)' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:78 [0x00000].
Loaded assembly: /Users/kevin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5DDB04B6-3BFA-4390-B22D-0492BAD99E3A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33A8D304-D62D-43A3-9839-C0A43FF720C6/LiquitMobileApp.iOS.app/System.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: ThreadStarted
Loaded assembly: /Users/kevin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5DDB04B6-3BFA-4390-B22D-0492BAD99E3A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33A8D304-D62D-43A3-9839-C0A43FF720C6/LiquitMobileApp.iOS.app/LiquitMobileApp.iOS.exe
2017-06-29 09:04:12.770 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[53524:1104160] warning: stat of /Users/kevin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5DDB04B6-3BFA-4390-B22D-0492BAD99E3A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33A8D304-D62D-43A3-9839-C0A43FF720C6/LiquitMobileApp.iOS.app/System.Net.Http.dll.mdb failed: No such file or directory
Loaded assembly: /Users/kevin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5DDB04B6-3BFA-4390-B22D-0492BAD99E3A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33A8D304-D62D-43A3-9839-C0A43FF720C6/LiquitMobileApp.iOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
```

*In here the rest of the assembly's are loaded correctly*

```
Loaded assembly: /Users/kevin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5DDB04B6-3BFA-4390-B22D-0492BAD99E3A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33A8D304-D62D-43A3-9839-C0A43FF720C6/LiquitMobileApp.iOS.app/SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/kevin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5DDB04B6-3BFA-4390-B22D-0492BAD99E3A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33A8D304-D62D-43A3-9839-C0A43FF720C6/LiquitMobileApp.iOS.app/SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3.dll [External]
InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: TargetHitBreakpoint
InspectorDebugSession(0): StateChange: EntryPointBreakpointRegistered -> EntryPointBreakpointHit
InspectorDebugSession(0): AgentBridge.InjectAssembly: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Interactive.framework/Versions/Current/Agents/iOS/Xamarin.Interactive.iOS.dll
InspectorDebugSession(0): StateChange: EntryPointBreakpointHit -> BreakdanceInvoking
Loaded assembly: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Interactive.framework/Versions/Current/Agents/iOS/Xamarin.Interactive.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Interactive.framework/Versions/Current/Agents/iOS/Xamarin.Interactive.dll [External]
InspectorDebugSession(0): StateChange: BreakdanceInvoking -> BreakdanceStarted
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: ThreadStarted
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: ThreadStarted
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: ThreadStarted
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: ThreadStarted
Thread started:  #8
InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: ThreadStarted
2017-06-29 11:01:48.379 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical: Stacktrace:
2017-06-29 11:01:48.380 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2017-06-29 11:01:48.380 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_sqlite3/NativeMethods.sqlite3_step (intptr) [0x00009] in <a63d6dc2db424db7bac9939dab923f4a>:0
2017-06-29 11:01:48.380 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_sqlite3.SQLitePCL.ISQLite3Provider.sqlite3_step (intptr) [0x00001] in <a63d6dc2db424db7bac9939dab923f4a>:0
2017-06-29 11:01:48.381 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_step (SQLitePCL.sqlite3_stmt) [0x0000b] in <5c4406fef20b4edeb9b55325c1027569>:0
2017-06-29 11:01:48.381 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at Akavache.Sqlite3.BeginTransactionSqliteOperation.<PrepareToExecute>b__7_0 () [0x00000] in C:\projects\akavache\src\Akavache.Sqlite3\Operations.cs:390
2017-06-29 11:01:48.381 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at Akavache.Sqlite3.SqliteOperationQueue.ProcessItems (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Akavache.Sqlite3.OperationQueueItem>) [0x00011] in C:\projects\akavache\src\Akavache.Sqlite3\OperationQueue.cs:290
2017-06-29 11:01:48.382 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at Akavache.Sqlite3.SqliteOperationQueue/<<Start>b__18_0>d.MoveNext () [0x0014f] in C:\projects\akavache\src\Akavache.Sqlite3\OperationQueue.cs:121
2017-06-29 11:01:48.382 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start<Akavache.Sqlite3.SqliteOperationQueue/<<Start>b__18_0>d> (Akavache.Sqlite3.SqliteOperationQueue/<<Start>b__18_0>d&) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:84
2017-06-29 11:01:48.382 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at Akavache.Sqlite3.SqliteOperationQueue.<Start>b__18_0 () [0x00027] in <67aced6c5c1a4c15b03e120d7300429d>:0
2017-06-29 11:01:48.383 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2879
2017-06-29 11:01:48.383 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502
2017-06-29 11:01:48.383 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback (object) [0x00006] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2865
2017-06-29 11:01:48.384 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:957
2017-06-29 11:01:48.384 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:904
2017-06-29 11:01:48.384 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task&) [0x00050] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2827
2017-06-29 11:01:48.385 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry (bool) [0x00058] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2760
2017-06-29 11:01:48.386 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.LongRunningThreadWork (object) [0x00006] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs:47
2017-06-29 11:01:48.387 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) [0x00025] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:72
2017-06-29 11:01:48.387 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:957
2017-06-29 11:01:48.387 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:904
2017-06-29 11:01:48.388 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) [0x0002b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:893
2017-06-29 11:01:48.388 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart (object) [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:87
2017-06-29 11:01:48.389 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00053] in <2f4074c3120b4d80802e10af84b67d41>:0
2017-06-29 11:01:48.389 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical: 
Native stacktrace:
2017-06-29 11:01:48.394 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   0   LiquitMobileApp.iOS                 0x00000001044e5241 mono_handle_native_crash + 257
2017-06-29 11:01:48.394 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   1   LiquitMobileApp.iOS                 0x00000001044f2310 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 288
2017-06-29 11:01:48.395 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000011137fb3a _sigtramp + 26
2017-06-29 11:01:48.395 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   3   ???                                 0x00006000000b9380 0x0 + 105553117025152
2017-06-29 11:01:48.395 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   4   ???                                 0x00000001292931f8 0x0 + 4985532920
2017-06-29 11:01:48.396 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   5   ???                                 0x000000012926ec2f 0x0 + 4985383983
2017-06-29 11:01:48.396 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   6   ???                                 0x0000000129251255 0x0 + 4985262677
2017-06-29 11:01:48.396 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   7   ???                                 0x000000012924fd72 0x0 + 4985257330
2017-06-29 11:01:48.397 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   8   ???                                 0x000000012924f23e 0x0 + 4985254462
2017-06-29 11:01:48.397 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   9   ???                                 0x00000001291f8849 0x0 + 4984899657
2017-06-29 11:01:48.397 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   10  ???                                 0x00000001291f764c 0x0 + 4984895052
2017-06-29 11:01:48.398 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   11  ???                                 0x00000001291f58f3 0x0 + 4984887539
2017-06-29 11:01:48.398 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.

=================================================================

InspectorDebugSession(3): HandleTargetEvent: TargetExited
InspectorDebugSession(3): Disposed
The app has been terminated.
Launch failed.
The app 'LiquitMobileApp.iOS' could not be launched on 'iPhone 6s iOS 10.3'. 
Error: An error occurred while executing MTouch.
Please check the logs for more details.
The app has been terminated.
```

[AppDelegate class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCNKd.png)

Comment: Do you get this error, when the app starts, when you press a specific button, when you navigate to a speicifc page? The error you listed above is a native error from the monotouch framework, there are several things it can be, but in and of itself, it's not enough to narrow down the problem. Have you put in break points around the applications entry points to see how far it gets intialising before it crashes?

Comment: I get this error every time i launch the app, he starts it up and then terminates it immediately. @Digitalsa1nt

Comment: Feel free to ask for information you need to help me @Digitalsa1nt

Comment: perhaps start with showing elements from your AppDelegate class, we can then see if theres anything glaringly obvious in there that might be causing the problem. It's also worth bearing in mind that you can get SiG errors from button click events that are assigned in the Storyboard file that don't exist in the class, so as I said there's a lot to do, to narrow it down :)

Comment: I have added a picture from my AppDelegate class, and there is nothing like button click events that are assigned in the Storyboard file and that don't exist in the class. @Digitalsa1nt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our disccusion in the comments, the image you attached, as well as the following element in the SIG error:

```
2017-06-29 11:01:48.380 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_sqlite3.SQLitePCL.ISQLite3Provider.sqlite3_step (intptr) [0x00001] in <a63d6dc2db424db7bac9939dab923f4a>:0
2017-06-29 11:01:48.381 LiquitMobileApp.iOS[1321:58615] critical:   at SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_step (SQLitePCL.sqlite3_stmt) [0x0000b] in <5c4406fef20b4edeb9b55325c1027569>:0
```

and that your initialising this (SQLitePCL) in appdelegate, I'd hazard a guess that it's the most likely cause of the error being thrown.

```
SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();
```

I believe this thread may shed some light on a solution: [Here](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/issues/106)

Comment: Deleting -> SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init(); from the AppDelegate class, did it for me thanks!